# Merging 2 scripts

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I've been tasked with compiling a list of all our security groups and grabbing specific information about these groups but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get all the information onto one Csv.

This does a great job at getting all the bulk items I need from these groups.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * |

where {$_.GroupCategory -eq "security"} |
Where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Builtin*"} |
Where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*CN=Builtin*"} |
Where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups*"} |

Select DistinguishedName, GroupScope, Name, SamAccountName |

Export-csv -LiteralPath C:\Results\ListSecGroups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

And this script is my attempt at getting all the information to compile together with a count of the group memberships.

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * |

where {$_.GroupCategory -eq "security"} |
Where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Builtin*"} |
Where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*CN=Builtin*"} |
Where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups*"}

ForEach ($Group in $Groups){

    (Get-ADGroup $Group.DistinguishedName -Properties *).member.count

    Select DistinguishedName, GroupScope, Name, SamAccountName |

    Export-csv -LiteralPath C:\Results\ListSecGroups.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append

    }
```

I will also be adding in another column for the date these groups have been edited, that way we can see what groups are truly inactive despite having members.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Are you trying to include details of _group members_ along with the group information? Can you show us what the desired output should look like?

Comment: Absolutely. So the output i'm looking for is one big Csv file that has the group names listed out with all of the information in the first scrip and then an additional column with the number of members in that group. When I run the second script however it just spits out a long list of numbers that show the number of group members. I'm looking to combine the results into one Csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you'll want to use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) expression when calling `Select-Object`:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * |
  Where {$_.GroupCategory -eq "security"} |
  Where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Builtin*"} |
  Where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*CN=Builtin*"} |
  Where {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups*"} |
  Select DistinguishedName, GroupScope, Name, SamAccountName, @{Name='MemberCount';Expression={(Get-ADGroup $_.DistinguishedName -Properties member).member.Count}} |
  Export-csv -LiteralPath C:\Results\ListSecGroups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This will create a new property named `MemberCount` for each input object, and populate it with the member count

Comment: This is spot on! Thank you for this! I knew there was a way to get this to work!